# Is it possible to store an array of foreign keys in a json column?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 7 and its support for JSON columns, I would like to store in a column an array of foreign keys to another table. Is it possible? Does it support `include` linq?

For example, the entity is `Product`. This product can be multiple tags. Each tag is is codified in the `Tag` SQL table with additional columns such as color, icon, etc.

The `Product` entity would have a property:

```
public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

mapped to SQL Server as a `varchar`.

For example - table `Tags`:

| Id | Name | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dangerous | Red |
| 2 | Fragile | Green |
| 3 | Expensive | Blue |

Table `Products`:

| Product Id | Product Name | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Cyanide | [1] |
| 101 | Glass | [2,3] |
| 102 | Pen | [] |

At the end, I would like to able to do something like:

```
Context.Products.Include(p => p.Tags)
```

Is it possible? I have not found any similar example.

Comment: why use a json column for this instead of a normalized form?

Comment: It is a bad ideea to do that. You will have no data integrity if somehow a tag is deleted... the id will stay in all products and you will have a problem to easy add a new tag to a product.